# Drag and Drop on v-textarea vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to implement a simple Drag and Drop on vuetify v-textarea. I'm getting problem once I click the v-textarea, it removes the value from a dropped  component. I don't even know if it's cause of my code or just isn't available on vuetify v-textarea features. I provide a snippet below;

**TEMPLATE**

```
<v-textarea outlined dense @drop="drop($event)" @dragover="allowDrop($event)" placeholder="Paragraph" v-model="_paragraph"/>


<v-btn outlined dense color="#0057AD" draggable="true" @dragstart="drag($event)" :value="'{{date}}'">Date</v-btn>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
    /*
    * To get the value from dragged element
    *
    * @return void
    */
    drag(event){ event.dataTransfer.setData("text", event.target.value); },

    /*
    * To set the value from dragged element into an object 
    *
    * @return void
    */
    drop(event){ 
        event.target.value += event.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        this.setText(event.target.value);
    },
    
    /*
    * To prevent some actions when dropping value
    *
    * @return void
    */
    allowDrop(event){ event.preventDefault() },
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to update the `_paragraph` variable in `drop()` method.

```js
drop(event){ 
  event.target.value += event.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  this.setText(event.target.value);
  this._paragraph = event.target.value; // update the value of _paragraph.
}
```

[Here is a working demo.](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-sinoussi-vjod0?file=/src/components/Playground.vue)

Also, prefixing your `paragraph` variable with an ***underscore*** might give you an error [since they are reserve for Vue's internal properties](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2098#issuecomment-168091787). However, you can still access it via `$data._paragraph` but I recommend to just remove the underscore completely. It's much cleaner.

Comment: Thanks sir, this solved my problem :) thanks kabayan!

Comment: Slight error in the sample code: `draggable` should be `:draggable`, otherwise lots of warnings from the debug console.