# Why this odd warning from Vue / Vuetify / Vite?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vite

I am constructing an array of Vuetify 'chips' that can have data dragged from one to the other:

```
<v-container id="endgrid" style="max-width: 300px; position: relative;">
  <v-row v-for="(row,r) in endGrid">
      <v-chip  size="x-large"  
       v-for="(chip,c) in row"
        :key="chip.name" 
        draggable="true"
        @drop="drop($event)"
        @dragover="allowDrop($event)"
        @dragstart="drag($event)"
        :id=idString(1,r,c)
        > {{ chip.name }}  </v-chip>
  </v-row>
</v-container>
```

and it works as expected. But during the document creation I am getting this warning (in the debug console) for every one (of 25) `chip` creations:

```
[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "draggable". Expected Boolean, got String with value "true". 
   at <VChip size="x-large" key=43 draggable="true"  ... >
```

I'm sure the correct syntax for `draggable` is with a string, not a Boolean. Although if I remove the quotes, the warnings still appear - but the code still works.
I'm concerned that

- this may be hiding something else wrong in my code
- even if not, those warnings appearing in a browser's debug console don't look good!

Since it may be relevant, the data used to construct the grid looks like this:

```
onBeforeMount(() => {
  var index = 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    endGrid[i] = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        endGrid[i][j] = {
            "name" : i*10+j,
            "id" : index,
            "row" : i,  
            "col" : j,
            "list": 'end'
        };
        ++index;
    }
  }

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to bind `draggable` first in order to pass boolean:

```
:draggable="true"
```

Comment: This will probably work. Additionally, what also might work is just `draggable` without anything else.

Comment: Thank you. I copied the code from another 'working' answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63698737) , so my mistake propogated from there.